# What determines the rankings in GTA Heists?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In heists, every player, at the end of every round, is given a rank: Platinum, Gold, Silver, or Bronze.

What determines what rank you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the exact formula is well hidden inside the game code, but generally, I'd say the following activities definitely contribute positively towards your ranking:

- Killing enemies.
- Causing damage (for instance, damaging Lester's car in the first heist mission is known to give people platinum).
- Completing mission objectives.